# Problem with .find_element() from python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tiktok

I need to find the "upload" button and input to upload the video. Below is the markup of the elements and my code.
[Input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqxOd.png)
[Upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPIdS.png)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def test():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    upload_url = "https://www.tiktok.com/upload?lang=en-EN"
    login_url = "https://www.tiktok.com/login"
    print("Log in manually and press ENTER", end = '')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(login_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    input()
    print("Loading upload page...")
    driver.get(upload_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    path = ".../yt_to_tt_uploader/yt_videos/YMbO9YYzvVw.mp4"
    upload = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
    upload.send_keys(path)
    upload_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[class='css-y1m958']")
    upload_button.click()
```

It's raising error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@type = 'file']
```

I tried to find it by XPATH, CLASS_NAME, text, but maybe i was wrong.
I need to upload video in the field and click "upload"

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not able to locate this element `//input[@type='file']` in your code. Try using an explicit wait and see if it works, below code for your reference:

```
# wait 20 seconds before looking for element
upload = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='file']")))
```

If using `presence_of_element_located` doesn't work, then try `visibility_of_element_located`. Below is the code:

```
# wait 20 seconds before looking for element
upload = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='file']")))
```

Import statements required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I see one more issue in your other XPath, `@` is missing:

Change from `//button[class='css-y1m958']` to `//button[@class='css-y1m958']`

Comment: It throws me timeout exception
```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:275:16
```